# Jenkins: run gradle directly Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

There is a Job of type `Pipeline` on Jenkins.
`Gradle` plugin is installed.

I try to run gradle tasks directly but without success.

Current pipeline script:

```
node {
    stage('Compile') {
        // First variant
        gradle {
            tasks: 'clean'
            tasks: 'compileJava'
        }

        // Second variant
        gradle tasks: 'clean'
        gradle tasks: 'compileJava'

        // Third variant
        gradle('clean')
        gradle('compileJava')
    }
```

This script doesn't fail but does just nothing.

Output to the console:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Compile)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

How can I run gradle directly from the pipeline script?

Comment: Alternatively, try `sh 'gradle clean compileJava'`

Comment: Thanks.
Actually, I have working script: gradle is called via shell as in your sample.
But I deceided to make it via built-in command. It seems it is not good idea :)